# Send a custom NFC APDU command to a HCE device with PN532 python

Tags: python, flutter, nfc, mifare, pn532

I have a Waveshare PN532 NFC hat for Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to develop an Android app using Flutter. The app also utilizes Android HCE with [this Dart plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_host_card_emulation). I need the app to send some data when the device is near the NFC reader, I used the `await NfcHce.addApduResponse(6, [0,1,2,3,4,5]);` function provided by the plugin to send some data (the array) when the app receives an APDU command on port 6. Now I'm trying to send the custom APDU command using the PN532 reader. According to the plugin documentation, the APDU command should look like this `00A4040607A000DADADADADA`. I'm not sure how to use the python PN532 library to send the custom command. Any ideas on how to achieve this?